# Why does the following React code work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update a `p` element in realtime while I type on an input element. The following React code works perfectly. However, if I remove the `value` attribute completely from the `input` element, the code STILL works!

```
class ControlledInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: ''
        };
    }
    handleInput = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value
        });
    }
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <input
            value={this.state.input}
            onChange={this.handleInput} />
        <p>Input: {this.state.input}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

So my questions are:

- What does the `value={this.state.input}` line do?
- Why does the program still work without that line?

Comment: Let's put it this way: do you know what the `value` attribute does in pure HTML?

Comment: React renders the input html itself, and keeps some state for them, so it shouldn't really be there. The value will just be used as kind of a start up value, once you start modifying it, react will handle the changes and keep the value up to date. A more correct way of doing such manipulations would be with the `ref` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `value={this.state.input}` assigns the value of the form to the input box from your component. **Your code still works because the event handler still fires when you change the text in the textbox and react doesn't re-render your input.** The state of the input value is implicitly in the state of the DOM but this state isn't from your component.

If you had TWO inputs that used the same state, then when you type, the second input won't update. This is where you'll see something different from expected because you omitted the `value={this.state.input}`. If you include that in both input values then your text boxes will mirror each other.

```
class ControlledInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: ''
        };
    }
    handleInput = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value
        });
    }
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <input
            onChange={this.handleInput} />
        <p>Input: {this.state.input}</p>



        <input
            onChange={this.handleInput} />
        <p>Input: {this.state.input}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
};
```

in the code above, one of the input's won't update when both should have the same state :)

Comment: But who would make something that maps 2 textboxes like that? I would rather like to see the correct way of handling state changes and access input elements or basic html elements handling using the ref callback

Comment: @Icepickle the code above was made to illustrate an example. I think its very plausible that someone would want text they type to appear in multiple places. And I would argue that using `refs` to set state using raw element references is [*not* the react way to do it](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).

Comment: At least, not in the string way, no :)

Comment: @RicoKahler If I am manually typing in the textbox, I don't see the need to include `value={this.state.input}` and the program should work perfectly fine, right? Other than the case that you have stated, which is highly unlikely to occur in any of my work as a developer, I should be fine without the value attribute, am I correct?

Comment: @MiniGunnR yes in practice, you don't need to set this. however in the case where you need to set a default value, well there's a property [`defaultValue`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) you can set! use that instead of `value` :). I would say it's good practice to always set `defaultValue`

Answer (score 0):

> What does the value={this.state.input} line do?

This line sets the value attribute from the input using your state variable `input`, in your case it will initialise it with `''` (nothing) at the start (i.e., this is equivalent to `<input value="" ...>`)
If you change your `this.state.input` to something like

```
    this.state = {
        input: 'foo'
    };
```

you should see how the input value changes to `foo` upon the start of your program.

> Why does the program still work without that line?

Because you are already setting it to be empty at the start so it doesn't actually change anything in your program. Your `onChange` event handler still fires.